# Labels/Image in CollectionViewCell not centered

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a custom collectionview cell that has a couple labels and an image, all centered horizontally in the cell. It looks great in storyboard (everything is constrained to the center X). The cells are adjustable size to the screen width so that 2 cells show up in each row.

When I run the app with different screen sizes, none of the items are centered. The labels and the image are centered properly to each other, but they are off center within the cell. Anyone have any experience solving this? Thanks a lot![![enter image description here][1]][1]

EDIT 1:
I checked, it's not the constraints on the cell that's messing it up.

Edit 2: 
It seems to be in my sizeForItemAtIndexPath:. When I comment out this func, the cells are laid out perfectly, but the spacing gets messed up. The bigger the screen, the farther apart the cells get. I want there to be 2 pts of space between all the cells.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

      return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width / 2 - 3, height: collectionView.frame.size.width / 2 - 3)
   }
```

Comment: I've had the experience of the cell's `contentView` not sizing itself correctly before.  What if after you dequeue it you do something like `cell.contentView.frame = cell.contentView.bounds`?

Comment: Please include a screen shot of your layout constraints.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with the constraints, see my edit, thanks!

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No solution yet. Either the cells are spaced close together but the cell formatting is messed up, or the cells are spaced far apart but the cell is laid out perfectly. It's so weird, what to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sound's like you created centering constraints between the label and images themselves, and not the actual cell. Make sure you have created a centering constraint between your label and the cell, and between your image and the cell. There's no telling though, without a picture of your current constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to yours, and what worked for me was adding an implemention for `collectionView:layout:insetsForSectionAtIndex:` (as defined in the [UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:) protocol) in my delegate.

For example:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                        layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
        insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured it out, it was keeping the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` how I have it above. Then my `insetForSectionAtIndex:` is 2 on each side. Then the `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex` is 2.0 and `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex` is 2.0. Everything works properly, thanks again!